# Is there a way make the fields of a GraphQLObjectType dynamic/non-required inorder to recive a dynamic key value pair

Tags: graphql

I am trying the GraphQL for the first time. I have a express-graphql server connected to MySQL for hypothetical juice shops, where a owner has ability add or remove or rename the serve type.

*For example*

- Shop A has serves like "Cute Small","The Regular" and "Extravaganza"
- Where as shop B serves like "Xsmall","small","medium","large" and "Xlarge"

As the GraphQL fields are mandatory, I am unable think of solution for this particular scenario.

**In short, I would love to know if there is a way to write a GraphQLObjectType where the fields can be any/not mentioned.**

*Snippet of a menu type, were the fields is very specific*

```
var typeDef = new GraphQLObjectType({
 name: "Menu",
 fields: {
  name: { type: GraphQLString },
  small_serve: { type: GraphQLFloat },
  regular_serve: { type: GraphQLFloat },
  medium_serve: { type: GraphQLFloat },
  large_serve: { type: GraphQLFloat },
 },
});
```

*GraphiQL*

```
{
menus{
  name,
  small_serve,
  regular_serve,
  medium_serve,
  large_serve
}
}
```